# CBOR encoding for a Double gives me wrong Output

Tags: java, kotlin, serialization, encoding, cbor

I am using the CBORTree Library from Google right now, I am trying to encode a Double like this:

```
val cborData = CborObject.createFromJavaObject(129.33)
val cborBytes = cborData.toCborByteArray()
```

My output for this is:

```
FB-40-60-2A-8F-60-00-00-00
```

But the output should be like this referencing cbor.me:

```
FB 40602A8F5C28F5C3 # primitive(4638754411406489027)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Link to Lib: [lib](https://github.com/google/cbortree)

Comment: I don't know that library or it's api but `createFromJavaObject()` seems wrong here. Note that in your case you will be using a `Double` instance due to auto-boxing while your example refers to the value as a primitive. So I'd assume you'd need to use a different method to create the data object.

Comment: Having a look at the [API](https://google.github.io/cbortree/releases/latest/apidocs/com/google/iot/cbor/package-summary.html) it seems you'd need to use `CborFloat.create(129.33)`.

Comment: I tried that aswelll but it is the same behaviour, added the lib on the top